# "Element not found" error when adding dns via netsh command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, netsh

When trying to add dns entries via netsh commands, I get "Element not found" errors.

`netsh interface ip set dns “Wi-FI” static 10.0.0.1 1`

What is the correct command format for setting both primary and secondary dns via command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following format sets the primary and secondary DNS entries correctly on Windows 8:

```
netsh interface ip set dns “Wi-Fi” static 10.0.0.1
netsh interface ip add dns “Wi-Fi” 10.0.0.2 index=2
```